# cumulative plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumulative-sum

I'm learning to use `ggplot2` and am looking for the smallest `ggplot2` code that reproduces the `base::plot` result below. I've tried a few things and they all ended up being horrendously long, so I'm looking for the smallest expression and *ideally would like to have the dates on the x-axis* (which are not there in the `plot` below).

```
df = data.frame(date = c(20121201, 20121220, 20130101, 20130115, 20130201),
                val  = c(10, 5, 8, 20, 4))
plot(cumsum(rowsum(df$val, df$date)), type = "l")
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:5, y=cumsum(val))) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Just remove `geom_point()` if you don't want it.

**Edit:** Since you require to plot the data as such with x labels are dates, you can plot with `x=1:5` and use `scale_x_discrete` to set `labels` a new `data.frame`. Taking `df`:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = 1:5, y = cumsum(val))) + geom_line() + 
        geom_point() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust = 1)) + 
        scale_x_discrete(labels = df$date) + xlab("Date")
```

[image]

Since you say you'll have more than 1 `val` for "date", you can aggregate them first using `plyr`, for example.

```
require(plyr)
dd <- ddply(df, .(date), summarise, val = sum(val))
```

Then you can proceed with the same command by replacing `x = 1:5` with `x = seq_len(nrow(dd))`.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty long compared to the `plot`. Can `ggplot` at least redeem itself by adding dates on the `x` axis, probably rotated by 90 degrees? :)

Comment: quote: "and ideally would like to have the dates on the x axis (which are not there in the plot below)."

Comment: I also tried editing your post to fix it for the case where there are more than 1 val's per date, but the edit hasn't gone through.

Comment: Thanks! Just add another entry to the `df` with the same date and some `val` and see the `plot` output. It'll be the cumulative daily sum of `val`.

Comment: I'll mark this answered, but please fix the `rowsum` bit for future reference. Can't say this is pretty, but thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure what your confusion is about. It's two different values for the same date and I'm interested in the cumulative sum plot of values, but indexed by date, as opposed to observation (which is what you did). I updated my post with a slightly modified version of your answer, with that issue fixed. Ok, I'll bite, what is `ggplot2` *really* all about?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27799/discussion-between-eddi-and-arun)

Answer (score 7):

After a couple of years, I've settled on doing:

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(as.character(date), '%Y%m%d'), cumsum(val))) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 3):

[Jan Boyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8239069/jan-boyer) seems to have found a more concise solution to this problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090073/geom-bar-geom-line-with-different-y-axis-scale), which I have shortened a bit and combined with the answers of [Prradep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4836511/prradep), so as to provide a (hopefully) up-to-date-answer:

```
ggplot(data = df, 
   aes(x=date)) +
geom_col(aes(y=value)) +
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = cumsum((value))/5, group = 1), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
ylab("Value") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust = 1))
```

Note that `date` is not in Date-Format, but `character`, and that `value` is already grouped as suggested by [Prradep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4836511/prradep) in his answer above.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something - but how is this more concise?