# Plot geom_bar() and geom_line() with double Y axis - Error with geom_line() overwriting geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've followed the answers found to a similar question [here].([geom_bar + geom_line: with different y-axis scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090073/geom-bar-geom-line-with-different-y-axis-scale))

I have a dataframe:

```
structure(list(ReleaseYear = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), ReleaseMonth = c("JAN", "JAN", "JAN", 
"JAN", "JAN", "FEB", "FEB", "MARCH", "MARCH", "MARCH", "MARCH", 
"MARCH", "MARCH", "MARCH", "APRIL", "APRIL", "APRIL", "APRIL", 
"APRIL", "MAY"), ProductionOrder = c(10024497, 10025083, 10025082, 
10025207, 10024619, 10024597, 10025071, 10024495, 10024948, 10024949, 
10025560, 10025583, 10025561, 10025604, 10025741, 10025799, 10025798, 
10025904, 10025836, 10025661), NilesHeatNo = c("8G44683", "8K44915", 
"8K44931", "8F45082", "8G45098", "8K45265", "8K45308", "8H45420", 
"8G45530", "8F45528", "8G45573", "8F45630", "8G45615", "8H45757", 
"8H45911", "8J45988", "8F46002", "9G46088", "8V46078", "8K46185"
), LookupCode = c("C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C2 - OXYGEN - LOW", 
"C2 - OXYGEN - LOW", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", 
"C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", 
"C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", 
"C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", 
"C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", 
"C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH", "C1 - OXYGEN - HIGH"
), ScrapWeight = c(0, 1900, 1900, 4700, 1900, 1700, 1700, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 20289, 11200, 1900, 1900, 19777, 20843, 2500, 1600, 
1700), Melt = c("8G", "8K", "8K", "8F", "8G", "8K", "8K", "8H", 
"8G", "8F", "8G", "8F", "8G", "8H", "8H", "8J", "8F", "9G", "8V", 
"8K"), MeltNo = c(44683, 44915, 44931, 45082, 45098, 45265, 45308, 
45420, 45530, 45528, 45573, 45630, 45615, 45757, 45911, 45988, 
46002, 46088, 46078, 46185), NilesWeight = c(20062, NA, NA, 20452, 
20692, NA, NA, 20885, 13490, 13546, 20500, 20289, 20150, 20695, 
20681, 19777, 20843, NA, NA, NA), CantonWeight = c(NA, 20618, 
19947, NA, NA, 20363, 20290, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 18551, 20150, 20398), Grade = c("766GV", "566JV", "566JV", 
"766BV", "766FU", "666GV", "666JV", "766FV", "766IV", "766IV", 
"764KV", "766BV", "764KV", "766BV", "766BV", "766BV", "766BV", 
"565SV", "566BV", "666FL"), MeltDate = structure(c(16770, 16788, 
16789, 16808, 16810, 16825, 16828, 16839, 16848, 16848, 16852, 
16857, 16861, 16869, 16884, 16892, 16893, 16901, 16904, 16910
), class = "Date"), MeltControlRelease = structure(c(1452902400, 
1453075200, 1453248000, 1454976000, 1453766400, 1455148800, 1456185600, 
1456099200, 1457481600, 1457481600, 1457395200, 1458259200, 1458691200, 
1459123200, 1460419200, 1461024000, 1461024000, 1461283200, 1461715200, 
1462838400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    O2Range = c("16/190", NA, NA, "16/20", "16/20", NA, NA, "16/19", 
    "17/20", "17/20", "14/18", "16/20", "14/18", "17/20", "16/20", 
    "16/20", "16/20", NA, NA, NA), ScrapPct = c("50", NA, NA, 
    "50", "0", NA, NA, "50(T)", "50(T)", "50(T)", "70", "70(T)", 
    "70(T)", "50(T)", "50(T)", "70", "70", NA, NA, NA), ReasonLate = c(NA, 
    "LOW O2 TOP, CROP 2900", "Low O2 btm, crop 1900", "HIGH O2 BOTTOM, CROP 4700 LBS", 
    "HIGH O2 BOTTOM, CROP 1900", "HIGH O2 BOTTOM,  CROP 1700 LBS", 
    "HIGH O2 BTM", "HIGH O2 BOTTOM, CROP 1900", "HIGH O2 CTR", 
    "HIGH O2 CTR", "HIGH O2 TOP AND CENTER", "HIGH O2, FORGE TO SCRAP", 
    "HIGH O2 TOP, CROP 11200", "USED MONICO SCRAP, HIGH O2 BTM", 
    "HIGH O2 BTM, CROP 1900", "High O2, forge to scrap (sister to 8F46002)", 
    "High O2, forge to scrap (sister to 8J45988)", "HIGH O2 BTM", 
    "HIGH O2 BOTTOM, CROP 20150", "HIGH o2 BOTTOM, CROP 1700 LBS"
    ), O2High = list("190", NA_character_, NA_character_, "20", 
        "20", NA_character_, NA_character_, "19", "20", "20", 
        "18", "20", "18", "20", "20", "20", "20", NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_), O2Low = list("16", NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, "16", "16", NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        "16", "17", "17", "14", "16", "14", "17", "16", "16", 
        "16", NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Turnings = c(0, 
    NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA), Furnace = c("G", "K", "K", "F", "G", "K", "K", "H", 
    "G", "F", "G", "F", "G", "H", "H", "J", "F", "G", "V", "K"
    ), DailyAverageRelativeHumidity = c(91L, 65L, 53L, 70L, 81L, 
    52L, 67L, 75L, 81L, 81L, 71L, 62L, 68L, 56L, 57L, 76L, 73L, 
    68L, 58L, 47L), DailyPrecipitation = structure(c(13L, 151L, 
    2L, 29L, 39L, 151L, 151L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 151L, 25L, 8L, 
    45L, 19L, 21L, 5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.00", "0.01", 
    "0.02", "0.03", "0.04", "0.05", "0.06", "0.07", "0.08", "0.09", 
    "0.10", "0.11", "0.12", "0.13", "0.14", "0.15", "0.16", "0.17", 
    "0.18", "0.19", "0.20", "0.21", "0.22", "0.23", "0.24", "0.25", 
    "0.26", "0.27", "0.28", "0.29", "0.30", "0.31", "0.32", "0.33", 
    "0.34", "0.35", "0.36", "0.37", "0.38", "0.39", "0.40", "0.41", 
    "0.42", "0.43", "0.44", "0.45", "0.46", "0.47", "0.48", "0.49", 
    "0.50", "0.51", "0.52", "0.53", "0.54", "0.55", "0.56", "0.57", 
    "0.58", "0.59", "0.60", "0.61", "0.62", "0.63", "0.64", "0.65", 
    "0.66", "0.67", "0.68", "0.69", "0.70", "0.71", "0.72", "0.73", 
    "0.74", "0.75", "0.76", "0.77", "0.78", "0.79", "0.80", "0.81", 
    "0.82", "0.83", "0.84", "0.85", "0.86", "0.87", "0.88", "0.89", 
    "0.90", "0.91", "0.92", "0.93", "0.94", "0.95", "0.96", "0.99", 
    "1.00", "1.02", "1.04", "1.05", "1.06", "1.07", "1.08", "1.10", 
    "1.11", "1.12", "1.18", "1.19", "1.20", "1.21", "1.22", "1.23", 
    "1.24", "1.25", "1.27", "1.28", "1.30", "1.32", "1.35", "1.37", 
    "1.41", "1.42", "1.44", "1.46", "1.47", "1.49", "1.52", "1.54", 
    "1.58", "1.62", "1.68", "1.69", "1.71", "1.74", "1.84", "1.86", 
    "1.95", "1.96", "1.97", "2.06", "2.08", "2.11", "2.21", "2.67", 
    "3.50", "3.96", "3.99", "T"), class = "factor"), DailySnowfall = structure(c(2L, 
    63L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 63L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 63L, 63L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 15L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "0.1", "0.2", 
    "0.3", "0.4", "0.5", "0.6", "0.7", "0.8", "0.9", "1.0", "1.1", 
    "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", "1.8", "1.9", "10.7", 
    "2.0", "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", "2.5", "2.6", "2.7", "2.8", 
    "2.9", "3.0", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.4", "3.5", "3.6", "3.7", 
    "3.8", "3.9", "4.0", "4.1", "4.2", "4.3", "4.4", "4.6", "4.7", 
    "4.8", "5.1", "5.2", "5.4", "5.5", "5.9", "6.4", "6.6", "6.7", 
    "6.8", "7.2", "7.5", "7.9", "T"), class = "factor"), DailyWeather = structure(c(80L, 
    159L, 1L, 80L, 147L, 73L, 159L, 147L, 161L, 161L, 1L, 159L, 
    127L, 74L, 74L, 136L, 147L, 145L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "BR", "BR FG", "BR HZ", "BR HZ FG", "BR RA", "BR TS FG", 
    "BR TS RA", "DU", "DZ", "DZ BR", "DZ FG BR", "DZ FG MIFG BR", 
    "DZ FZDZ FG BR", "DZ FZDZ SN BR", "DZ FZDZ SN PL FG BR RA", 
    "DZ FZRA FZDZ SN BR RA", "DZ FZRA FZDZ SN PL BR RA", "DZ MIFG BR FG", 
    "DZ MIFG BR HZ FG", "DZ SN BR", "DZ SN BR RA", "FC TS RA BR", 
    "FG", "FG BR", "FG BR HZ", "FG FZFG BR", "FG FZFG BR HZ", 
    "FG FZFG MIFG BR", "FG MIFG", "FG MIFG BR", "FG MIFG BR HZ", 
    "FZDZ BR", "FZDZ FG FZFG BR", "FZDZ SN", "FZDZ SN BR", "FZDZ SN BR BLSN RA", 
    "FZDZ SN BR RA", "FZDZ SN BR RA FG", "FZDZ SN FG FZFG BR", 
    "FZDZ SN FZFG BR FG", "FZFG BR FG", "FZFG MIFG BR FG", "FZRA", 
    "FZRA FZDZ SN BR", "FZRA FZDZ SN BR HZ", "FZRA FZDZ SN BR RA", 
    "FZRA FZDZ SN PL BR", "FZRA FZDZ SN PL BR BLSN", "FZRA FZDZ SN PL BR RA", 
    "FZRA FZDZ SN PL BR UP", "FZRA FZDZ SN PL FG FZFG BR RA", 
    "FZRA PL BR", "FZRA SN BR", "FZRA SN BR BLSN", "FZRA SN BR RA", 
    "FZRA SN PL", "FZRA SN PL BR", "FZRA SN PL BR RA", "FZRA SN RA", 
    "HZ", "MIFG BR", "MIFG BR FG", "MIFG BR HZ", "MIFG BR HZ FG", 
    "MIFG BR RA FG", "MIFG BR TS FG", "MIFG BR TS RA FG", "MIFG FG", 
    "MIFG FG HZ", "MIFG RA FG", "MIFG TS FG", "RA", "RA BR", 
    "RA BR DZ", "RA BR FG", "RA BR HZ", "RA BR TS", "RA DZ", 
    "RA DZ BR", "RA DZ BR HZ", "RA DZ FG BR", "RA DZ FG MIFG BR", 
    "RA DZ FG MIFG BR TS", "RA DZ FZDZ FG BR", "RA DZ FZDZ FZFG BR FG", 
    "RA DZ FZDZ SN BR", "RA DZ FZDZ SN FG FZFG BR", "RA DZ FZRA FZDZ BR", 
    "RA DZ FZRA FZDZ SN BR", "RA DZ FZRA FZDZ SN FG BR", "RA DZ FZRA FZDZ SN PL BR", 
    "RA DZ FZRA FZDZ SN PL BR UP", "RA DZ FZRA FZDZ SN PL FG BR", 
    "RA DZ FZRA FZDZ SN PL FZFG BR", "RA DZ FZRA SN BR", "RA DZ FZRA SN FG BR", 
    "RA DZ FZRA SN FZFG BR FG", "RA DZ FZRA SN PL FG BR", "RA DZ FZRA SN PL FG MIFG BR", 
    "RA DZ FZRA SN PL FZFG BR FG", "RA DZ MIFG BR FG", "RA DZ MIFG FG", 
    "RA DZ PL BR", "RA DZ SN", "RA DZ SN BR", "RA DZ SN FG BR", 
    "RA DZ SN PL BR", "RA DZ SN PL FG BR", "RA FG BR", "RA FG BR HZ", 
    "RA FG BR TS", "RA FG FZFG MIFG BR", "RA FG MIFG", "RA FG MIFG BR", 
    "RA FG MIFG BR HZ", "RA FG MIFG BR TS", "RA FZDZ SN", "RA FZDZ SN BR", 
    "RA FZDZ SN BR BLSN", "RA FZDZ SN FG BR HZ BLSN", "RA FZDZ SN FG FZFG BR", 
    "RA FZRA BR", "RA FZRA FZDZ BR", "RA FZRA FZDZ SN BR", "RA FZRA PL BR", 
    "RA FZRA SN", "RA FZRA SN BR", "RA FZRA SN FZFG BR FG", "RA FZRA SN PL BR", 
    "RA FZRA SN PL BR BLSN", "RA FZRA SN PL FG BR", "RA FZRA SN PL FZFG BR BLSN FG", 
    "RA HZ", "RA MIFG BR", "RA MIFG BR FG", "RA MIFG BR HZ", 
    "RA MIFG BR HZ FG", "RA MIFG BR TS FG", "RA MIFG DZ FG", 
    "RA MIFG FG", "RA MIFG TS FG", "RA PL", "RA PL BR", "RA SN", 
    "RA SN BLSN", "RA SN BR", "RA SN BR BLSN", "RA SN BR HZ", 
    "RA SN FG BR", "RA SN FG FZFG BR", "RA SN FZFG BR FG", "RA SN MIFG BR FG", 
    "RA SN PL", "RA SN PL BR", "RA SN PL FG BR", "RA SN PL FG MIFG BR", 
    "RA TS", "SN", "SN BLSN", "SN BR", "SN BR BLSN", "SN BR FG", 
    "SN BR HZ", "SN FG", "SN FG BR", "SN FG BR BLSN", "SN FG FZFG BR", 
    "SN FG FZFG BR BLSN", "SN FZFG BLSN FG", "SN FZFG BR", "SN FZFG BR BLSN FG", 
    "SN FZFG BR FG", "SN FZFG BR UP FG", "SN FZFG FG", "SN MIFG BR FG", 
    "SN PL", "SN PL BR", "SN PL BR HZ", "SN PL FZFG BR BLSN FG", 
    "SN PL FZFG BR FG", "TS", "TS BR", "TS FG MIFG BR", "TS FG MIFG RA BR", 
    "TS FZDZ SN PL BR BLSN RA", "TS GR RA", "TS GR RA BR", "TS GR RA FG BR", 
    "TS MIFG BR FG", "TS MIFG BR HZ FG", "TS MIFG BR RA FG", 
    "TS MIFG FG", "TS RA", "TS RA BR", "TS RA BR DZ", "TS RA BR FG", 
    "TS RA BR HZ", "TS RA DZ BR", "TS RA DZ FG BR", "TS RA DZ FG MIFG BR", 
    "TS RA DZ MIFG BR HZ FG", "TS RA DZ PL BR", "TS RA FG", "TS RA FG BR", 
    "TS RA FG BR HZ", "TS RA FG MIFG", "TS RA FG MIFG BR", "TS RA FG MIFG BR HZ", 
    "TS RA MIFG BR", "TS RA MIFG BR FG", "TS RA MIFG BR HZ FG", 
    "TS RA MIFG FG", "TS RA MIFG HZ FG", "TS RA SN BR", "TS RA SN PL BR", 
    "TS SN PL BR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've tried to create a bar chart of total events by month from 2016 to 2018, with an overlaid line graph showing a sum of scrap weight for each month by year. My ggplot call is:

```
ggplot(O2Data %>% filter(year(MeltDate) != 2019), aes(x=factor(months(MeltDate), levels=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August",
                                             "September","October","November","December")))) +
        geom_bar(stat="count", aes(fill=months(MeltDate))) +
        geom_line(aes(y=ScrapWeight, group=factor(year(MeltDate)), color=factor(year(MeltDate)))) +
        stat_summary(aes(y=ScrapWeight/1000), fun.y=sum) +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1000, name = "Scrap Weight")) +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5), legend.position="none") +
        labs(title = "Count of O2 Scrap Codes by Month (2016-2018)", x = "Month", y = "Count")
```

I'm getting a final plot that looks not at all like what I was trying for, but can't quite figure out my error.

[image: Graph1 (incorrect)]

I can plot the first half, but the call to geom_line() seems to override it. Any ideas on how to get the line graph to work as I'm intending?

```
ggplot(O2Data %>% filter(year(MeltDate) != 2019), aes(x=factor(months(MeltDate), levels=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August",
                                             "September","October","November","December")))) +
        geom_bar(stat="count", aes(fill=months(MeltDate))) +
        # geom_line(aes(y=ScrapWeight, group=factor(year(MeltDate)), color=factor(year(MeltDate)))) +
        # stat_summary(aes(y=ScrapWeight/1000), fun.y=sum) +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1000, name = "Scrap Weight")) +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5), legend.position="none") +
        labs(title = "Count of O2 Scrap Codes by Month (2016-2018)", x = "Month", y = "Count")
```

[image: Graph2 (partial)]

Comment: Your bars go up to 40, while your lines go up to 20000. You can't just plot those together. The secondary axis draws some new numbers on the right hand side, but it doesn't rescale the `geom_bar` and `geom_line` to both be visible.

Comment: Axeman, I was attempting to scale by dividing the y values, such as in: aes(y=ScrapWeight/1000). Does this address it, or is there something else I need to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Axeman's comment above, I found my error, which was with scaling.

Additionally, I was improperly calling geom_line() and stat_summary().

The corrected code:

```
ggplot(O2Data %>% filter(year(MeltDate) != 2019), aes(x=factor(months(MeltDate), levels=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August",
                                             "September","October","November","December")))) +
        geom_bar(stat="count", fill="antiquewhite3") +
        geom_line(stat='summary', aes(y=ScrapWeight/100, group=factor(year(MeltDate)), color=factor(year(MeltDate)))) +
        stat_summary(aes(y=ScrapWeight/100), fun.y=sum) +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*100, name = "Scrap Weight"), limits = c(0, 48)) +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5), legend.position="none") +
        labs(title = "Count of O2 Scrap Codes by Month (2016-2018)", x = "Month", y = "Count")
```

[image: Corrected Graph]